# Sumatoria de cuadrados en R con algebra lineal - Machine Learning

Tags: r, matlab, machine-learning, octave

Estoy pasando algunos scripts que tengo de **Matlab** y **Octave** a **R** que sirven para minimizar la diferencia de los cuadrados de una función de costos dada una hipótesis, en relación a los datos observados.

Lo anterior se emplea como parte de algoritmos de aprendizaje supervisado o autónomo.

El intercambio entre los diferentes lenguajes de programación ha ido bien, sin embargo al trabajar con vectores, he notado algo que llamó mucho mi atención y quisiera exponer lo encontrado.

> Para simplificar, se tiene un vector `x` de dimensiones `1x10: (1 fila con 10 columnas)` con los valores `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`.

Si quisiera obtener la suma de los cuadrados aplicando algebra lineal sería el vector `x` por (DOT) su transpuesta, eso da `385` la notación en **Matlab** y **Octave** sigue la notación que uno esperaría: `x*x'`, `dónde x': transpuesta de x`.

En **R** sería muy sencillo hacer `x <- 1:10; sum(x*x)` y se obtiene `385` de tipo numérico en **Matlab** y **Octave** sería muy similar también `x = 1:10; sum(x.*x)` el punto `.` indica que es uno a uno la multiplicación y el resultado sigue siendo `385`.

**R** también provee una función [t - está en inglés](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/t.html).

Para resumir lo explicado en el enlace previo: el vector `x` mediante la función `t` cambiará su dimensión a `10x1`, así mismo, la [multiplicación de matrices y vectores - está en inglés](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/matmult.html) para **R**, se emplea el operador `%*%` entonces al convertir `x*x'` a:

> - `x %*% t(x)` se obtiene una matriz de `10x10`.
> - `t(x) %*% x` se obtiene el resultado `385` pero de tipo matriz.
> - `x %*% x` se obtiene el resultado `385` pero de tipo matriz.

Las dos últimas expresiones, si bien dan el resultado, al no ser la notación estándar en algebra lineal, esto podría ser una barrera para adaptar modelos u algoritmos existentes.

Asimismo **R** provee una función `drop` si el resultado va ser una matriz de `1x1` para que el resultado sea del tipo numérico.

> Entonces cuál podría ser una recomendación para trabajar con vectores en **R** si se va emplear algebra lineal.

**NOTA:** En el post se menciona las dimensiones del vector `x` pero sí aplicas en **R** `dim(x)` se obtendrá `NULL` ya que no es una matriz o un array, sólo se habló sobre las dimensiones del vector `x` para hacer las comparaciones respectivas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un muy buen punto el que planteas, pareciera que el lenguaje es inconsistente  cuando estas dos instrucciones retornan valores totalmente distintos

```
x %*% t(x)
t(x) %*% x
```

El problema aquí son dos puntos muy importantes:

- `x` es un `vector` y `t(x)` es una matriz
- La precedencia de los operandos determina el funcionamiento final

Sin embargo si consultas la documentación del producto matricial, es decir [`%*%`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/matmult.html), sobre el final encontrarás:

> For matrix crossproducts, crossprod() and tcrossprod() are typically
>   preferable

Es decir, lo recomendable es usar [`crossprod()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/crossprod.html), vemos su documentación:

> Given matrices x and y as arguments, return a matrix cross-product.
>   This is formally equivalent to (but usually slightly faster than) the
>   call t(x) %*% y (crossprod) or x %*% t(y) (tcrossprod).

En tu ejemplo sería:

```
crossprod(x, x)

     [,1]
[1,]  385
```

Y, de paso, para verificar eso de que `crossprod()` podría ser algo más rápida que la notación `%*%`, podemos verificar que efectivamente es así:

```
f1 <- function() {t(x) %*% x}
f2 <- function() {crossprod(x, x)}
microbenchmark("%*%"=f1(), 
               "crossprod()"=f2(),
               times=1000L)

Unit: microseconds
        expr   min     lq      mean median      uq      max neval
         %*% 8.590 9.3925 14.212453  9.707 10.1960 4049.536  1000
 crossprod() 2.863 3.2820  7.136024  3.631  4.0155 3354.616  1000
```

Comment: Efectivamente @PatricioMoracho no se trata de sólo transcribir código de un lenguaje a otro. Bien con lo del rendimiento, se me había pasado, incluso para comparar con `pracma::dot` rápidamente usé `i<-Sys.time(); drop(crossprod(x, x)); Sys.time()-i`en un `loop 1000 veces` luego `summary(resultadoTest*10^6)` para ser justos (el resultado debe ser numérico) y aún así es más veloz que la función `dot` del precitado paquete: `mean = 3.343 / 28.90 microsegundos respectivamente`

Answer (score 1):

**R** es muy versátil, cuando se define `x<-1:10` y luego se calcula `x %*% x` (`=385 del tipo matriz`) es un [producto escalar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producto_escalar).

Si bien es correcto decir que `x` es un vector, las operaciones en **R** están optimizadas para trabajar mayormente con tablas, data.frame, consultas sobre datos, etc. y ahí estriba su ventaja, por tanto, se tiene que ir con cuidado al momento de efectuar **operaciones que impliquen algebra lineal.**

La recomendación que puedo hacer para este caso particular es, si tienes un vector `x<-1:10` en **R**, conviértelo en matriz:

```
x <- matrix(x, nrow=1)
res <- x %*% t(x)
# res <- drop(res) opcional convierte a numérico la matriz 1x1
```

O en un array (pero la notación es más larga)

```
x <- array(x, dim = c(1, length(x)))
res <- x %*% t(x)
# res <- drop(res) opcional convierte a numérico la matriz 1x1
```

Esto ayudaría mucho, pero sería una solución parcial también, ya que no se contempla las operaciones entre matrices (vectores) de `1xn` con matrices de `nxm`.

Una solución a ello es el paquete `pracma` por ejemplo para obtener `385` con `x<-1:10` bastaría hacer `dot(x,x)` siendo el resultado del tipo numérico.