# Puede alguien explicarme este codigo de R para replicarlo en Java

Tags: java, r, pip, packages

```
ROS <- function(data, perc_min = 50, perc_over = NULL, classes = NULL){
  y <- data[[ncol(data)]]
  if (is.null(classes)) classes <- extract_classes(y)

  min_idx <- which(y == classes[["Minority"]])

  min_size <- length(min_idx)
  maj_size <- nrow(data) - min_size

  sample_size <- compute_oversample_size(majority_size = maj_size,
                                         minority_size = min_size,
                                         perc_min = perc_min,
                                         perc_over = perc_over)
  if (sample_size == 0) return(data)

  # Avoid for instance sample(22, size = 30, replace = TRUE)
  if (min_size == 1) min_idx <- rep(min_idx, 2)
  append_idx <- sample(min_idx, size = sample_size, replace = TRUE)

  rbind(data, data[append_idx, , drop = FALSE])
}
```

Este código es la función ROS que se utiliza para balancear un conjunto de datos en minería de datos. Esta disponible y explicado pues es codigo de un paquete de R [rdrr.io/github/RomeroBarata/bimba/src/R/ROS.R](http://rdrr.io/github/RomeroBarata/bimba/src/R/ROS.R)

Comment: Este codigo es la funcion ROS que se utiliza para balancear un conjunto de datos en mineria de datos

Comment: Esta disponible y explicado pues es codigo de un paquete de R https://rdrr.io/github/RomeroBarata/bimba/src/R/ROS.R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Consideraciones

Hay que empezar diciendo primero que las funciones incluidas en el código posteado, corresponden a: [`library(bimba)`](https://github.com/RomeroBarata/bimba),

> Dicho paquete tal como indica su autor: *se encuentra en constante desarrollo, en tal sentido no se encuentra disponible aún en el CRAN de R*.

Sobre lo anterior ya se preguntó aquí: [Cómo conseguir el package “XXX” si no está disponible para la versión R w.y.z](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/235926/c%C3%B3mo-conseguir-el-package-xxx-si-no-est%C3%A1-disponible-para-la-versi%C3%B3n-r-w-y-z)

Por lo expuesto, se tiene situaciones como las siguientes: al revisar el repositorio de github en cuestión, no he sido capaz de ubicar el script o la documentación respectiva que indique el funcionamiento de `compute_oversample_size`, lo anterior también aplica con `extract_classes` -si alguien puede indicar dónde están estupendo-.

Adicionalmente, el autor de `bima` ha definido la función **ROS** como `Random Over-Sampling:` que en español significa: `Sobremuestra aleatoria`, esto se emplea básicamente para introducir sesgo, seleccionando más muestras de una clase que de otra, a efecto de balancear los datos.

Más sobre el anterior procedimiento en [Oversampling and undersampling in data analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oversampling_and_undersampling_in_data_analysis) -no he encontrado documentación en español-

## Alternativas

**R** ofrece por suerte un paquete oficial llamado [ROSE](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROSE/ROSE.pdf), aquí se puede descargar [Package source: ROSE_0.0-3.tar.gz](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROSE/index.html) para una posible integración con **Java** como se acotará más adelante.

> Una recomendación es revisar bien los conceptos en este articulo empleando dicho paquete [Imbalanced Classification in R](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/practical-guide-deal-imbalanced-classification-problems/) en especial los relacionados con `Oversampling`.

Considero esta sugerencia válida sí se quiere pasar de **R** a **Java** el código fuente del citado paquete, porque se tiene que verificar que la implementación efectuada, arroje con los mismos datos y parámetros, resultados acordes a los que se obtendría si estos se efectuaran con el paquete **ROSE** en **R** antes de lanzarlo a producción.

En este [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/240046/sumatoria-de-cuadrados-en-r-con-algebra-lineal-machine-learning), he comentado algunas consideraciones con respecto al algebra lineal en **R** para Machine Learning.

## Sobre Java

Cuando se menciona **R** y **Java** es importante indicar que no se trata del paquete `rJava`, este permite correr **Java** dentro de **R**.

Asimismo siento decir que existe un proyecto para correr **R** dentro de **Java** llamado [JRI](https://www.rforge.net/JRI/) al ver la biblioteca la última actualización que ha tenido, corresponde al 2017, no sé si el proyecto ha sido abandonado o sigue en funcionamiento, habría que buscar más al respecto.

No obstante hay unos post donde indican como hacer la implementación de **R** a **Java** con **JRI**, pero por cuestiones de tiempo y al ser tan extenso este tema, no he podido probar:

- [JAVA-R-INTEGRATION WITH JRI FOR ON-DEMAND PREDICTIONS](https://comsystoreply.de/blog-post/java-r-integration-with-jri-for-on-demand-predictions)
- [Java R
  Interface (JRI) Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100875/java-r-interface-jri-setup#)
- [Problems with JRI: Este soluciona al
  parecer algunos inconvenientes con el primer Post JAVA-R-INTEGRATION
  WITH JRI....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790505/problems-with-jri)

En mi opinión si no se está buscando algo muy especial..., se tome el paquete **ROSE** -revisar el [copyright](https://www.r-project.org/Licenses/) y la licencia [GPL-2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/licenses/GPL-2)- y lo llames a través de una herramienta si no es **JRI** similar, para su integración mediante un `Bridge`.

Aunque hay un aspecto importante a considerar: **ROSE** también depende de los siguientes paquetes: `MASS, nnet, rpart, tree` y aquí comienza el trabajo de hormiga porque se tendría que ver que funciones de **ROSE** se van a usar e ir descartando paquetes... y los incluidos ver cuales necesitan para funcionar...

En este post [¿Es posible usar un paquete no estándar en Repl.it?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/235163/es-posible-usar-un-paquete-no-est%C3%A1ndar-en-repl-it) se detalla lo anterior, asimismo indique en uno de los comentarios, que mediante [pip (package manager)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)) se podía instalar el paquete que se requiere, con todas sus dependencias fuera de **RStudio**. Aclaro que esto no lo he probado en Eclipse o [Android Studio](https://pypi.org/project/android-sdk-updater/)

La situación antes expuesta no es ajena a `bimba` al ver la documentación [DESCRIPTION](https://github.com/RomeroBarata/bimba/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) se indica que paquetes requiere y cuales son sugeridos.

Por último, es complejo migrar un código de un lenguaje que no se está familiarizado -con las sutilezas que puede traer o las dependencias que puedan existir entre sus bibliotecas- a otro que ya se domina (ya sea de R a Java o de Java a R), por tal motivo en esta situación considero que tener un algoritmo especifico para lo que se quiere, sería mucho más útil, ya que respalda la lógica de la implementación... esto de mi experiencia es más valioso en última instancia.

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad me ayudo muchisimo su respuesta